# How to pass numerical value of terminal to caculator?

Tags: linux

I want to do `5-9=-4` and remove `-` minus sign then add `3` in `4`.

e.g.

```
5-9=-4. 4 + 3 = 7
```

How can I do this?

I tried `echo "5-9" | bc | last + 3`.

But it does not work.

I want to do in single line linux command.

Comment: This looks a lot less like programming and a lot more like simple shell scripting, so Super User would arguably be a rather better place. Otherwise, tag with some specific shell you're using and go from there.

Comment: You can try `x=$(( 5 - 9 )); x=$(( ${x#-} + 3 )); echo $x`.

Answer (score 0):

A little hacky, but here:

```
echo "5-9" | bc | sed 's/-//' | sed 's/.*/\0+3/' | bc
```

The first sed call deletes the first minus sign, turning -4 to 4.  The second concatenates
the 4 into 4+3.

Comment: Hi,Thank you. It works fine. I want to know hoe last sed command (sed 's/.*/\0+3/') works?

Comment: The /.*/ section selects the entire input with a regular expression.  The . means any character and * means zero or more of them, combining to mean the entire input.  Then you get /\0+3/, which means replace with the selection, \0, followed by +3, which altogether replaces .*, or everything, with \0+3, or everything+3

Comment: Thank You. But I want to know why 0,zero is needed? If I place 1 or other value instead of 0 zero then I am getting error.

Comment: It is not 0, but \0, which is an escape character which stores the entire selection.  Using \1 selects stuff in the first set of \(\), so an equivalent expression with \1 would be sed 's/\(.*\)/\1+3/'.  Link: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#uh-4

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
echo -e  "5-9 \n  . * -1 \n .+3" | bc | tail -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use parentheses, this solution should run in several different shells:

```
echo "-(5 - 9) + 3" | bc
```

The following runs on bash:

```
echo $((-(5 - 9) + 3))

let "a = -(5 - 9) + 3"; echo $a
```